# Spring OAuth Server JBDCTokenStore Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to add Database to Spring OAuth Server sample code.
Here is the dataSource configuration.

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/OAuth");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
    driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("password");
    return driverManagerDataSource;
}
```

And EndpointConfig

```
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public JdbcClientDetailsService clientDetailsService() {
        return new JdbcClientDetailsService(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService());
    }
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        //return new InMemoryTokenStore();
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore);
        endpoints.userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler);
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
```

But I get error on JbdctokenStore, JdbcClientDetailsService work fine.

error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource required
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'tokenStore' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/security/oauth/examples/sparklr/config/OAuth2ServerConfig$AuthorizationServerConfiguration.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Factory method [public
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore
>   org.springframework.security.oauth.examples.sparklr.config.OAuth2ServerConfig$AuthorizationServerConfiguration.tokenStore()]
>   threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource required

I couldn't figure out what happen.
Database and Table is all fine.(I use the sql file the sample gave.)

---

```
        @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        //return new InMemoryTokenStore();
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource());

    }

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/OAuth");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("a89019");
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }
```

I just add a new bean under it and change dataSource to dataSource(),
and it work.
I can't get it, why JdbcClientDetailsService work with orignal one.
But JdbcTokenStore need a new one.
How can I change this part of code, the code looks messy because of duplicate code.

Comment: Do you have `@Configuration` annotation on `JdbcTokenStore` class?

Comment: No, but I solve the error by adding the duplicate code under it. I don't know why it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mark your datasource bean with `@Primary`. See more details here: [77. Data Access](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html)